# show only values in my second array php

Tags: php, arrays

I have two arrays which I am comparing. The comparison is working perfectly as follows:

```
  $tmp = array_diff_key($arr1, $arr2);
  $echo $tmp;
```

However, I only want to display the values that exist in array 2 that don't exist in array 1.

Edit: Ok so thank for everyone's help.  How ever I am still unable to make it work.

I am now using

```
   $tmp = array_diff($arr2, $arr1);
  var_dump($tmp);
```

which prints out the following:

```
  array(1) { [0]=> array(3) { [0]=> string(4) "cars" [1]=> string(4) "vans" [2]=> string(6) "people" } }
```

So, I'll explain a little.

Array 1 has cars, vans (this is pulled from the database).

Array 2 has cars, people  (this is entered from a form).

I'm trying to only show values that are not in the database so I thought $tmp would echo just people as cars is in the database and vans is in $arr1

I hope thats clear as its even confusing me writing it ;)

If I var_dump both array individually I get

```
    array(3) { [0]=> NULL [1]=> string(4) "cars" [2]=> string(4) "vans" } array(1) { [0]=> array(2) { [0]=> string(6) "people" [1]=> string(5) "tanks" } }
```

Comment: how does that differ from your code?

Comment: Please don't use tags that don't apply to your question

Comment: `$echo` should be `echo` and this won't print the contents of arrays anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$tmp = array_diff_key($arr2, $arr1);
$echo $tmp;
```

`echo $tmp` will just output `'Array'` I think, so you probably have to loop over it (perhaps with `foreach`) to display each individual value, or use `var_dump`.

`array_diff_key` also works with keys, `array_diff` with values (you mention "values" in your question).

Comment: Ok after clearing my cache it would appear this answer works great. thank you much :)

Answer (score 2):

Use `array_intersect`. `array_intersect` gives values which are in both.

```
$tmp2 = array_intersect($arr1, $arr2);
var_dump($tmp2);
```

Edit : Misread the question. `array_diff` will serve the purpose. `array_diff` returns values from argument1 which are not present in the rest of the arguments.

```
$tmp2 = array_diff($arr2, $arr1);
var_dump($tmp2);
```

Edit : In your case, your `$arr2` has an array inside it which has the values. So, you will need to `array_diff($arr2[0], $arr1);`

Here's a working [fiddle](http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/g4u-dyp).

Comment: I have changed now to array_diff but its still not working.  My main question has been updated with your code and the output of a var_dump

Comment: Can you please also add the `var_dump` of the individual arrays to the question?

Comment: Done that array1 and array2 next to each other.  This time in array 2 I entered tanks, people

Answer (score 1):

you can do as follows :

```
foreach($tmp as $key=>$value) {
    if(isset($arr2[$key])) {
        echo $arr2[$key];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

From my understanding of `array_diff_key`, the function returns an array containing all the entries from argument1 whose keys are not present in any of the other arrays. So just put `$arr2` into the first argument.

So your code should be:

```
$tmp = array_diff_key($arr2, $arr1);
$echo $tmp;
```

[Source](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-diff-key.php)

Comment: thanks @MikeB I have tried array_diff_key that way round and it just presents me with array(0) { } event though I know it should say people as cars is in array 1

Answer (score 1):

swap the direction:

```
$tmp = array_diff_key($arr2, $arr1);
  $echo $tmp;
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are concerned with values and not key values, then you should just use `array_diff()`.  You would also need to reverse the order of the arrays in the parameters.  Finally echoing an array isn't going to show you what you want, use `var_dump()`. So putting it all together:

```
$tmp = array_diff($arr2, $arr1);
var_dump($tmp);
```

Comment: thanks for your help but that just prints array(0) { }  I have now updated my question